# Excluding iPad from wp_is_mobile

Tags: functions, mobile

I am eperiencing a very annoying problem. I built my website with media queries and is_mobile (thinking is_mobile would be the same as smaller screens. How foolish of me.) but after some testing apparently the iPad kind of screws it up (okay, actually I did).

All my problems could easily be solved if I could exclude an iPad from the wp_is_mobile function. How do I rewrite that function?

```
function wp_is_mobile() {
    static $is_mobile;

    if ( isset($is_mobile) )
        return $is_mobile;

    if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
        $is_mobile = false;
    } elseif ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== false // many mobile devices (all iPhone, iPad, etc.)
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false ) {
            $is_mobile = true;
    } else {
        $is_mobile = false;
    }

    return $is_mobile;
}
```

How would I change this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

t f's answer got me thinking. Actually, I can use the core function and adapt it as I like but just put everything in a new function. So here goes:

```
function my_wp_is_mobile() {
    static $is_mobile;

    if ( isset($is_mobile) )
        return $is_mobile;

    if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
        $is_mobile = false;
    } elseif (
        strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false ) {
            $is_mobile = true;
    } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== false && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad') == false) {
            $is_mobile = true;
    } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad') !== false) {
        $is_mobile = false;
    } else {
        $is_mobile = false;
    }

    return $is_mobile;
}
```

Comment: It's always good to find _own_ solutions, so +1 for this. However, I also updated my answer. I had a stupid _typo_ in there: I checked for `===` while I should have checked for `!==` instead - no idea how that happened, but now I fixed that. So, the above answer _should_ work as well - which I am absolutely **not** saying to make you accept it! It's just that, in essence, our answers/functions do the same - so I just wanted to find (and fix) what was wrong.

Comment: @tf That's what my comment was about! But, I am going to accept my own answer because I know this one works and I haven't tested your code. I don't want anybody to read this and use your answer if I haven't tested it. I feel sort of responsible for this thread. I hope you understand. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: Did you guys actually managed to test it live on an ipad? I'm trying right now without any success, ipad air, locally.

Comment: @kevin tested this on an iPAD 3, which worked.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I wanted to update it with the proper WordPress way of implementing the previous solutions. As of version 4.9.0, rather than implementing another function, they should filter the result of wp_is_mobile(). Thus:

```
function myprefix_exclude_ipad( $is_mobile ) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad') !== false) {
        $is_mobile = false;
    }
    return $is_mobile ;
}
add_filter( 'wp_is_mobile', 'myprefix_exclude_ipad' );
```

HOWEVER What really should have been done was to bite the bullet and rewrite the theme to work properly on tablets.  There were/are more tablet manufacturers than Apple.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the regularly updated [Mobile Detect PHP class](http://mobiledetect.net/) to create a custom function for detecting mobiles excluding tablets (thus iPads). At time of writing this answer, the [Github repo](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php) had most recently been updated to include detection for new Samsung tablets as of 3 months ago.

Assuming you place the required file in directory called `/includes/` in your theme, then you can add this code to your **functions.php**

```
require_once(get_template_directory() . '/includes/Mobile_Detect.php');

function md_is_mobile() {

  $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

  if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

then use the function `md_is_mobile()` as a substitute for `wp_is_mobile()`.

Comment: Isn't this solution dependent on the installation of a plugin containing the Mobile Detect class?

Comment: The Mobile Detect class dependency is handled by the first line of the code block above; no additional plugin is required. I should note that WordPress plugins based on this class do exist, such as [WP Mobile Detect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/), but this has not been updated for almost 2 years, so I personally prefer to use the PHP class directly, which appears to be actively developed.

Comment: Its a fair answer however you need to install the file Mobile_Detect.php which i'm referring to as the plugin.

Comment: That's fair enough!

Answer (score 2):

<s>I've rewritten (and, in my opinion, optimized) your function a bit:</s>

```
function wp_is_mobile() {
    static $is_mobile;

    if (isset($is_mobile))
        return $is_mobile;

    if (
        ! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])

        // bail out, if iPad
        && false === strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad')

        // all the other mobile stuff
        && (
            false !== strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile')
            || false !== strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android')
            || false !== strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/')
            || false !== strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle')
            || false !== strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry')
            || false !== strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini')
        )
    ) $is_mobile = true;
    else $is_mobile = false;

    return $is_mobile;
}
```

**// EDIT:**

Okay, once again...

Write a new function that internally uses the core function and *extend* it:

```
function my_wp_is_mobile() {
    if (
        ! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])

        // bail out, if iPad
        && false !== strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad')
    ) return false;
    return wp_is_mobile();
} // function my_wp_is_mobile
```

Now you can use your new `my_wp_is_mobile` function anywhere you want.

Comment: So, I can just put this inside my functions.php file and it will automatically overwrite the core function?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, my bad - I never used this (and thus didn't know it was WP core). Since the function is not pluggable, you **cannot** just put that in your `functions.php` file. I'll update my answer in a minute...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. But shouldn't the user agent for iPad return true?

Comment: Hm? I understood it like you wanted to exclude iPads from being treated as mobile devices - as they would by `wp_is_mobile`...? So, what does not work (as you would like to do)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an iPad myself, so I have to rely on information I get from friends. But currently I have a design which loads a sidebar if a user agent "!is_mobile" (is not mobile), but this is not necessary for the iPad because its resolution is large enough. My friends tell me that even though I used `if(!my_wp_is_mobile() )` the sidebar is still not being displayed. From which I deduct that the function doesn't work.

Comment: And what I meant by my comment is that I thought that the function checks "if user agent is NOT empty AND if it is false that user agent is iPad" return false. But I would say that I need "if user agent is NOT empty and if it is true that user agent is iPad"? Maybe it has to do with that you run the actual core function after the custom function as well? And then `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile')` will return true for iPad.

Comment: Figured it out (see my own answer). Thank you for the ideas though!