# Change the default number of posts to show on mobile version

Tags: posts, mobile

I want to change the default number of posts shown for my mobile site. Here is my theme's loop

```
          <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?> 
          <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
              <?php get_template_part( 'mobile-content' ); ?>    
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have 25 posts showing on desktop version set in wordpress settings but how can I show 15 posts per page for mobile version?

Comment: How precisely are you implementing and detecting mobile version of the site?

Comment: using server side for user agent detection

Comment: Server side _what_?

Comment: This plugin-> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Firstly*, you need to detect mobile devices, probably the easiest and a built in possibility is [`wp_is_mobile`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile). It is simpler then other solutions that are available, but works reasonably well. It can be altered, if necessary, take a look at this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114369/excluding-ipad-from-wp-is-mobile) for a first insight into that.

*Secondly*, if that concerns your main query, like your code suggests, you can use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter it.

Below a basic example on how to bring those together:

**Code:**

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse124949_alter_main_query_ppp_mobile');
function wpse124949_alter_main_query_ppp_mobile( $query ){
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    if( $query->is_main_query() && wp_is_mobile() ) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '15');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in your child theme functions.php or as a plugin to show 15 posts per page on mobile devices.

```
function custom_posts_per_page($query) {
    if (wp_is_mobile()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 15);
    } //endif
} //function

//this adds the function above to the 'pre_get_posts' action     
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page');
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?